# How can I get computer specific string/code

Tags: c++, c, macos

I need a code to take a computer specific string/code regardless of the operating system. It looks like the code below, I mean getCPU() give different results. I do not understand why, where I'm wrong?

Issues I've noticed:

1. Apparently after a reinstallation the result changes
2. In some rare cases, the result changes even if a reinstallation is not made

Where the problem is ?

````
#include <net/if_dl.h>      
#include <net/if_types.h>      
#include <ifaddrs.h>  
#include <mach-o/arch.h>  

   unsigned short hashMacAddress( unsigned char* mac ) { 
   unsigned short hash = 0;             

   for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; i++ )              
   {       
      hash += ( mac[i] << (( i & 1 ) * 8 ));           
   }       
   return hash;              
} 

    char *getMacHash() { 
            char* ret = new char[255];
            unsigned short mac1=0;
            unsigned short mac2=0;

               
     
   bool foundMac1 = false;   
       struct ifaddrs* ifaphead; 
       if ( getifaddrs( &ifaphead ) != 0 ) 
            return ret;  

     
       struct ifaddrs* ifap;     
       for ( ifap = ifaphead; ifap; ifap = ifap->ifa_next )                  
       {       
          struct sockaddr_dl* sdl = (struct sockaddr_dl*)ifap->ifa_addr;     
          if ( sdl && ( sdl->sdl_family == AF_LINK ) && ( sdl->sdl_type == IFT_ETHER ))                 
          {              
          if ( !foundMac1 )  
          {                  
             foundMac1 = true;                
             mac1 = hashMacAddress( (unsigned char*)(LLADDR(sdl))); //sdl->sdl_data) + sdl->sdl_nlen) );       
          } else {           
             mac2 = hashMacAddress( (unsigned char*)(LLADDR(sdl))); //sdl->sdl_data) + sdl->sdl_nlen) );       
             break;          
          }                  
          }    
       }       

       freeifaddrs( ifaphead );  

            sprintf(ret, "S_%d%d", mac1, mac2);

            return ret;     
    } 
                   
     #include <mach-o/arch.h>    
     unsigned short getCpuHash() {         
         const NXArchInfo* info = NXGetLocalArchInfo();    
         unsigned short val = 0;            
         val += (unsigned short)info->cputype;               
         val += (unsigned short)info->cpusubtype; 
         
         return val;             
     }   

         
    char *getCPU() {  
        char* ret = new char[255];
      unsigned short cpu;             
      cpu=getCpuHash();
      
      if (cpu>118)    
            sprintf(ret, "%dX%s", getCpuHash(), getMacHash());
      else
            sprintf(ret, "%dx%s", getCpuHash(), getMacHash());

        strcpy(ret,cleanChars(ret));

        if (strlen(ret)>50) {
            char tmp[50];
            strncpy(tmp, ret, 50);
            strcpy(ret, tmp);    
        }
      
        return cleanChars(ret);
    } ```
````

Comment: What exactly are you trying to identify? What is your criteria for "same machine"?

Comment: You won't get that code: explain us -in several paragraphs- how you could compile then run a C code without any operating system, and how you would do TCP/IP transmissions without any OS.

Comment: Also, what would happen if you add a new Ethernet controller to the computer? Some of them costs a few dozen of € or US$....

Answer (score 1):

getifaddrs() provides a linked list describing the network interfaces of the local system. No guarantee concerning the sequence is given. If you have multiple NICs, you should first sort the list before creating a hash.

On most operating systems arbitrary values can be assigned as MAC address. Some firmware like U-Boot even allows to pick a random number as MAC address (see configuration parameter CONFIG_NET_RANDOM_ETHADDR).

You could use the UUID of the root partition as identifier. Typically this is not changed unless the operating system is reinstalled. But of course the user can change it.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to fingerprint the machine using multiple hardware id's. I don't think that can be accomplish by one method for all the OS's.

getCPU() is not a good idea. Try exploring the network addresses with getifaddrs().

You can generate your own identifier too, instead of reading computer hardware id's generate your own id and store it somewhere, this way you can identify the machine later. I know, is less secure, since the user can copy and past the identifier file, but depending on what you are trying to do it might work.